# How to limit maximum seized resourcepool based on a parameter?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model where I need to limit the maximum seize able resourcepool capacity.

The structure is as follows,

ResourcePool A has a total capacity of 3.

Now, if a certain agent parameter has a value between 12 and 14, then the maximum available resourcepool capacity will be 2,, for other cases it will be 3.

Real Life Scenario:

*Allocation of product to the thin tanks is controlled by batch size, with the larger
tanks being reserved for larger batch sizes. For example, orders for batches of 6,000
gallons or fewer can only be transferred to the two 6,000-gallon or the two 10,000-gallon
tanks. The table below shows the allowable allocation by batch size to the various thin
tanks. Note that the 12,000- to 14,000-gallon batch sizes can only use two of the three
large 20,000-gallon thin tanks.*

Comment: that's a custom resource condition... you don't have to change the capacity, instead on the seize you have to select the possible resources you can use based on a condition.. if that's not the solution, your issue doesn't make sense in real life

Comment: The problem statement is as follows, I have also updated the question

Allocation of product to the thin tanks is controlled by batch size, with the larger
tanks being reserved for larger batch sizes. For example, orders for batches of 6,000
gallons or fewer can only be transferred to the two 6,000-gallon or the two 10,000-gallon
tanks. The table below shows the allowable allocation by batch size to the various thin
tanks. Note that the 12,000- to 14,000-gallon batch sizes can only use two of the three
large 20,000-gallon thin tanks.

Comment: in that case, my answer is what you need to do...